# Rename area folder in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm watching some classes and the instructor was teaching how to work with areas.

I'm stuck in the Areas folder renaming.

I've already changed the `Startup.cs` (below), but when I try to run it still request the `Areas` path

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Clear();
            options.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add(item: "/Modulos/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
            options.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add(item: "/Modulos/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
            options.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add(item: "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                name: "MyAreaProducts",
                areaName: "Produtos",
                pattern: "Produtos/{controller=Produto}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");        
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```

[image: Folder Schema]

[image]

Comment: You just configure for pages, not for views (so it still uses the default `Areas` path), look into here for configuring the view paths https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#change-default-area-folder-where-views-are-stored

Comment: Thank's, that was exactly that!